# Ajax Instant Messenger Using PHP

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Trying to create an AJAX IM for my site... 
need to load the part of page when row is inserted into mysql DB ... can anybody help me with this.. thanks in advance

Comment: You need to add some more information. Some code that you have created so far would also be useful

Comment: I agree with @SamWarren your question is asking for someone to create something for you. Not asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var  waittime=2000;
var intUpdate = null;


function verifDB(){

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "verifdb.php",
   success: function(msg){
    alert(msg),; 
   }
 });

intUpdate = setTimeout("verifDB()", waittime);
}
verifDB();
</script>
```

verifdb.php file is queried every 2000 ms to check on the database
you can put your file in requette verifdb.php
and you will have the answer in the variable msg

Comment: Thnkx for the help.. the only way is to check multiple times after a time interval.. doesnt this increase the load on DB .. is there any way to trigger an event for insert has happened

Answer (score 0):

**Client Side**

For assyncronous requests on the client side you can use JQuery or plain Javascript [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

**Server Side**

I know you've specified PHP but I would recommend you to check how [google channels](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) work and make a similar implementation in PHP.

Since checking having multiple users checking for updates on the database, I would recommend you to use memcache.

Something like:

```
$script_called_time = time();
while($memcache->get('last_message') < $script_called_time){
    usleep(100);
}

$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `date` > " . $script_called_time . "'");
...
```

This way the connection will be established and the user will receive a response when there's any...

Comment: thnkx for the help..will look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
  var chat = {
    messageToSend: "",
    messageResponses: [
      "I Love You",
      "I Wants to Kiss You.",
      'Hug Me!"',
      "Lets Sleep Together",
      "Lets go for a date",
      "Will you be physical with me?"
    ],
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.bindEvents();
      this.render();
    },
    cacheDOM: function() {
      this.$chatHistory = $(".chat-history");
      this.$button = $("button");
      this.$textarea = $("#message-to-send");
      this.$chatHistoryList = this.$chatHistory.find("ul");
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$button.on("click", this.addMessage.bind(this));
      this.$textarea.on("keyup", this.addMessageEnter.bind(this));
    },
    render: function() {
      this.scrollToBottom();
      if (this.messageToSend.trim() !== "") {
        var template = Handlebars.compile($("#message-template").html());
        var context = {
          messageOutput: this.messageToSend,
          time: this.getCurrentTime()
        };

        this.$chatHistoryList.append(template(context));
        this.scrollToBottom();
        this.$textarea.val("");

        // responses
        var templateResponse = Handlebars.compile(
          $("#message-response-template").html()
        );
        var contextResponse = {
          response: this.getRandomItem(this.messageResponses),
          time: this.getCurrentTime()
        };

        setTimeout(
          function() {
            this.$chatHistoryList.append(templateResponse(contextResponse));
            this.scrollToBottom();
          }.bind(this),
          1500
        );
      }
    },

    addMessage: function() {
      this.messageToSend = this.$textarea.val();
      this.render();
    },
    addMessageEnter: function(event) {
      // enter was pressed
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        this.addMessage();
      }
    },
    scrollToBottom: function() {
      this.$chatHistory.scrollTop(this.$chatHistory[0].scrollHeight);
    },
    getCurrentTime: function() {
      return new Date()
        .toLocaleTimeString()
        .replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");
    },
    getRandomItem: function(arr) {
      return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    }
  };

  chat.init();

  var searchFilter = {
    options: { valueNames: ["name"] },
    init: function() {
      var userList = new List("people-list", this.options);
      var noItems = $('<li id="no-items-found">No items found</li>');

      userList.on("updated", function(list) {
        if (list.matchingItems.length === 0) {
          $(list.list).append(noItems);
        } else {
          noItems.detach();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  searchFilter.init();
})();
```

[Messenger Using Jquery And PHP](https://codepen.io/ashokpachauri/pen/WNvaNgN)
If you needs any help regarding this answer feel free to contact me at pachauriashokkumar[at]gmail[dot]com if you need complete code with css JS and HTML Drop me an email i will email the code to you

External Files are needed

1. https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js
2. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js
3. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javve/list.js/v1.5.0/dist/list.min.js

Messenger Using JQuery And PHP Demo Is [Here](https://codepen.io/ashokpachauri/pen/WNvaNgN) Also Author of This Post on [PenCode](https://codepen.io/ashokpachauri/pen/WNvaNgN) is available for clarification over email pachauriashokkumar[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: How does your post relate to the question?

Comment: it is just an example for Ajax IM. he can use ajax instead of messageResponses object. @greybeard i just tried to help him through a relative way that i had handy at that time.
if you need specific solution please note that i have mentioned my email there to contact so that i can help him or any body else in particular thing.